# rsync to check/compare server1:/data/archive/ to server2:/data/archive/ and have the files synced to another destination such as server2:/data/?

Tags: bash, rsync

This has been tearing my hair out.

I need to:

1. compare server1:/data/archive/ to server2:/data/archive/ (through rsync, ssh, etc)
2. filenames that don't match, get copied (scp) to server2:/data/

server1 and server2 have ssh, scp, rsync access between eachother.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "filenames that don't match"? do you mean any files that aren't in both? could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming user "username" has ssh access to server2 from server1 you can sync changes made on server1 to server2 by running this on server1:

`rsync -nav /path/to/files/ username@server2:/path/to/files/`

The trailing slashes are significant, see `man rsync` for details.

The options used in this example are:
n = dry-run, just report what will be done without actually doing it
a = archive mode, preserves ownership details, links etc
v = be verbose

Once you are happy it is doing what you want, you can remove the n flag.

See `man rsync` for more options, like --exclude and --delete, -z for compression may be useful too.